# Crunchbase-Like Database(s) for Countries

Tags: data-request, companies

Where can I possibly look for IT companies, key people, investors, etc for a particular country to create my own dataset? Like crunchbase, but not global.

Comment: If the problem is that Crunchbase is global, why can't you simply filter to the country of interest?